# How to install/implement Hudson on rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ROR 3 application.i need to install and run hudson for continiuos integration testing.i am a bit confused with available resources from Internet...I need Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first ..

1. Download hudson from [war file for hudson][1]

   Mount war file in VMware(if you are using LInux on windows) OR From
   the terminal hit this command `java -jar hudson-2.2.1.war`

   third and last step .. Connect to localhost by
   `http://localhost:8080`...and see Hudson running . Moreover you can
   change the configuration setting .This link will help you http://injecting.by2.be/blog/2010/11/hudson_for_a_rails3_project.html by Ivo Dancet 
   ...hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do CI with Jenkins, which is a fork of Hudson. You might try something like [this guide](http://gistflow.com/posts/492-jenkins-ci-setup-for-rails-application-from-scratch) - it covers the process from top to bottom.

There are also gems like [lobot](https://github.com/pivotal/lobot) which can automate much of the process for you, if you're going to use AWS.